# Как удалить фон у Button в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такая кнопка, никак не могу понять почему у нее не удаляется белый фон.

Код

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('EasyStudy')
root.geometry('400x700')
root.resizable(False, False)

# Add image file
bg = PhotoImage(file="images/bg.png")

# Create Canvas
canvas1 = Canvas(root)
canvas1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# Display image
canvas1.create_image(0, 0, image=bg,anchor="nw")

# Buttons
ef_img = PhotoImage(file='images/EF.png')
Button_EF = Button(root, image=ef_img, borderwidth=0)
Button_EF_win = canvas1.create_window(200,230, anchor='center', window=Button_EF)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Сделайте изображению кнопки прозрачный фон.

Comment: Каким образом?)

Comment: С помощью программы GIMP. Это такой графический редактор.

Comment: У кнопки не получится убрать фон. Создавайте не кнопку, а просто картинку на холсте, привязывайте действие к событию через canvas.tag_bind